# Communicating between 2 Firefox Add-Ons (Cross-Extension Communication)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firefox-addon, communication

How do I pass data and messages between 2 Firefox Add-Ons (the way Google Chrome does it, [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html#external))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Firefox add-ons share the same global scope when you do an overlay (which essentially every add-on uses).  You just need to create some shared object to pass data back and forth on.

Comment: This works but adding to the global namespace is probably not the best strategy. I would say a better approach would be to use JavaScript modules (firefox 3) to create a singleton. See here  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_JavaScript_code_modules