# How to share information between cooperating Firefox WebExtensions

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, communication, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to create a straightforward extension for Firefox.

1. User hovers over some word on any page
2. Pull the dictionary definition of that word from a file inside the extension
3. Display it while still hovered

I am new to Firefox add-ons and WebExtensions, so here's what I'm wondering:

I want the dictionary **file(s) used by the extension to be local**, instead of referring to some online website each time.

Any given user might be interested in a different part of the entire dictionary (it contains entries in different languages, users might only want their own 1 or 2 languages) so I want to avoid forcing every user to download the entire dictionary base.

The way I have seen similar add-ons handle that before Firefox 5.* is that they offer the search-and-display add-on separately from the dictionary files which are each available as add-ons in their own right, only actually doing stuff if you have the master add-on installed.

However, none of those examples seem to have been updated for the WebExtensions API and do not support more recent versions of Firefox.
I have also been unable to find how to communicate between web extensions so far.

**My question being, how can I share information between 2 or more coorperating extensions** to achieve what I described.
And actually, if this seems really stupid for some reason I'm unaware of, do point out any more reasonable alternatives that allow me to **handle the dictionary files separately from the main extension**.

Possibly related questions I found:
[Communicating between 2 Firefox Add-Ons (Cross-Extension Communication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869477/communicating-between-2-firefox-add-ons-cross-extension-communication)
This one is from 2010 however, thus out of date as far as I could tell.

[Mozilla Addon Development - Communicating between windows with different domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382343/mozilla-addon-development-communicating-between-windows-with-different-domains)
Kind of a similar situation, but they want to pull the definitions from an online source, rather than a local one.

The closest thing I found on the Mozilla browser extension website is communicating between add-on and some native applications, not quite what I need I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Communicating between add-ons is a normal part of the functionality of [`runtime.sendMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage), [`runtime.connect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/connect), [`runtime.onMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage), and [`runtime.onConnect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onConnect).

Both `runtime.sendMessage()` and `runtime.connect()` have as their optional first parameter:

> `extensionId`

For `runtime.sendMessage()`, this is:

> `string`. The ID of the extension to send the message to. Include this to send the message to a different extension. If the intended recipient has set an ID explicitly using the [`applications`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/applications) key in manifest.json, then extensionId should have that value. Otherwise it should have the ID that was generated for the intended recipient.
>
> If extensionId is omitted, the message will be sent to your own extension.

For `runtime.connect()`, this is:

> `string`. The ID of the extension to connect to. If the target has set an ID explicitly using the [`applications`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/applications) key in manifest.json, then `extensionId` should have that value. Otherwise it should be have the ID that was generated for the target.

Both `runtime.onMessage`, and `runtime.onConnect` provide a `sender` property or parameter, either with the message, or as part of the port. This parameter/property is a [`runtime.MessageSender`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/MessageSender) which includes an `id` property which is:

> `id`
>
> - `string`. The ID of the extension that sent the message, if the message was sent by an extension. If the sender set an ID explicitly using the [`applications`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/applications) key in manifest.json, then `id` will have this value. Otherwise it will have the ID that was generated for the sender.
>
>   Note that in Firefox, before version 54, this value was the extension's internal ID (that is, the UUID that appears in the extension's URL).

Comment: Thank you, I completely overlooked this in favour of more obscure areas to search in.